# HTML disappearing after PHP function called

Tags: javascript, php, html

This displays the result of a button press. The idea is that it reads and writes from a file so that users in different browsers can see the same result.

I had some issues accessing the DOM originally but then discovered that after the first button press, everything below my php script is wiped `This area doesn't get shown after button click`

The easy workaround is to simply move the DOM element higher up but... I want to know...

Why is this area getting deleted? It's as if it's being treated like PHP.

```js
//Background Loop
function updateChat(){
            var file = 'word.txt?v=' + Date.now() ;
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    {
                        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                        console.log(allText);
                        document.getElementById("shownword").innerHTML = allText;
                    }
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
    setTimeout(updateChat, 500);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Random Word Generator</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="update.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="updateChat();">

<p id=shownword></p>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="word"
                class="button" value="Button1" id="button1"/> 
          
        <input type="submit" name="word"
                class="button" value="Button2" id="button2"/> 
    </form>
    
    <?php
    //This function gets called when button is pushed
    function postword(){
        $fp = fopen('word.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $_POST['word']);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    //When the button is pushed, the function will be called
    if (isset($_POST['word'])) {
        postword();
        return;
    }
    ?>

This area doesn't get shown after button click

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `return` after calling your function is preventing the following code from being executed.

Comment: Yeahhh that would do it. 5 noob points for me XD Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Just remove "return;" from the if(isset($_POST['word'])) { // your code } condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the "return;"

```
if(isset($_POST['word'])) {
  postword();
  // return;
}
```